# Finding a document, editing it, and putting it back in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb and I want to be able to edit a document and reinsert it WITHOUT duplicates. So far i have tried collection.findAndModify() but I couldn't get that to work. I have a collection like this:

```js
UserProfiles = [
  {
   userProfileID: 1,
   firstName: 'Austin',
   lastName: 'Hunter',
   email: 'ahun.....com',
   token: '',
   platform: '',
   password: 'incorrect',
   companyProfileID: 1,
   authentication: '',
   UserTopics: [
```

I want to be able to do this:

1 - grab the profile out of the object via searching for email match.

2 - when the email matches, edit the token and platform item.

3 - then put the document back in with no duplicates. So I can't just insert it again because that duplicates it.

Can anyone help me out on figuring this out?

Code:

```js
function registerUser(email, token, platform) {
 MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
     if (err) {
   console.log(err);
     } else {
   console.log("We are connected");
     }
  
  var collection = db.collection('UserProfile');
  collection.findAndModify({
         query: { email: email },
         update: { token: token, platform: platform }
        });
        db.close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
modelname.findOneAndUpdate({ email: var_email}, { $set: { token: var_token, platform: var_platform}}, { new: true }, function(err, doc) 
{
   //doc here has updated document, in case you need it. 
});
```

> var_email etc. is your variable name and email is field name in
>   database.

`{ new: true }` - This part is used to fetch updated document, you can chose to not have this in your code but then you wont get updated document in response.

Comment: That worked amazingly. EXACTLY like I was looking for. Thanks a ton. Ill select best answer in 6 minutes.

Comment: Cheers mate! @AustinHunter